Scalable approach instead of apply in python
I use apply to loop the rows and get the column names of feat1, feat2 or feat3 if they are equal to 1 and scored is equal to 0. The column names are then inserted into a new feature called reason.
This solution doesn't scale to larger dataset. I'm looking for faster approach. How can I do that?
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],
             'feat1_tax':[1,0,0],
             'feat2_move':[1,0,0],
             'feat3_coffee': [0,1,0],
             'scored':[0,0,1]})

def get_not_scored_reason(row):
    exclusions_list = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('feat')]
    reasons = [col for col in exclusions_list if row[col] == 1]
    return ', '.join(reasons) if reasons else None

df['reason'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_not_scored_reason(row) if row['scored'] == 0 else None, axis=1)

print(df)

   ID  feat1_tax  feat2_move  feat3_coffee  scored      reason
0   1          1           1             0       0  feat1_tax, feat2_move
1   2          0           0             1       0           feat3_coffee
2   3          0           0             0       1                   None


You can prefilter the columns (so you don't need to do it for each row - the result will be the same), that would shed some cycles. also row[col] has n log n complexity, if you have a lot of columns that might make a difference as well. I'd join 0s and 1s into a summary column and then iterate per-row, per-entry in your prefiltered columns list. That could even be done in parallel.

Cf. here and here. You want to change those 1 and 0 in the feat columns into bools with astype(bool), and then you're nearly there.

This is the pandas apply you talking about?

Another possible solution, around 8x faster than @Andrej Kesely's, according to rough estimates:
feat_columns = df.filter(regex=r"^feat").columns
reasons = df.mask(df["scored"] != 0, 0)[feat_columns].to_numpy()
df["reason"] = np.array(
    [", ".join(feat_columns[row == 1]) if np.any(row == 1) else None for row in reasons]
)

   ID  feat1_tax  feat2_move  feat3_coffee  scored                 reason
0   1          1           1             0       0  feat1_tax, feat2_move
1   2          0           0             1       0           feat3_coffee
2   3          0           0             0       1                   None


Thanks a lot. Why is df.mask(df["scored"] != 0, 0) nessacary?

@e-motta you can make it even faster ;)

@Henri to mimic the condition in your question: ... if row['scored'] == 0 else None. To achieve the same result, I'm setting all 'feat...' columns to 0 when scored == 1 before creating column 'reason'. Note that this doesn't affect the original data in df. If that isn't a requirement you can remove the mask, though.

You can further improve on @e-motta's approach (4 times faster) by using zip in the list comprehension and avoiding numpy.any (replace by the or operator):
feat = df.filter(regex=r'^feat')

df['reason'] = [', '.join(feat.columns[row == 1]) or None if s else None
                for row, s in zip(feat.to_numpy(), df['scored'].eq(0))]

If the number of "feat" columns is reasonable, a dot product is even faster:
feat = df.filter(regex=r'^feat')
s = (feat@(feat.columns+', ')).str[:-2]
df['reason'] = s.mask(s.eq('')|df['scored'].ne(0), None)

Output:
   ID  feat1_tax  feat2_move  feat3_coffee  scored                 reason
0   1          1           1             0       0  feat1_tax, feat2_move
1   2          0           0             1       0           feat3_coffee
2   3          0           0             0       1                   None

timings
Using 3 "feat" columns and a variable number of rows:

Using 10k rows and a variable number of "feat" columns, the dot product approach starts being slower than the comprehension above ~200 "feat" columns:

So you could imaging an hybrid approach that selects the best method based on the number of "feat" columns:
def auto_reason(df, thresh=200):
    feat = df.filter(regex=r"^feat")
    if feat.shape[1] > thresh:
        df['reason'] = [', '.join(feat.columns[row == 1]) or None if s else None
                for row, s in zip(feat.to_numpy(), df['scored'].eq(0))]
    else:
        s = (feat@(feat.columns+', ')).str[:-2]
        df['reason'] = s.mask(s.eq('')|df['scored'].ne(0), None)

auto_reason(df)


Relative to the list comprehension:


Great and informative answer, as always. +1

This is a very solid answer, wow.

You can try:
columns = df.filter(regex=r"^feat")
df["reason"] = (columns * columns.columns).agg(
    lambda x: ", ".join(x[x.ne("")]) or None, axis=1
)

print(df)

Prints:
   ID  feat1_tax  feat2_move  feat3_coffee  scored                 reason
0   1          1           1             0       0  feat1_tax, feat2_move
1   2          0           0             1       0           feat3_coffee
2   3          0           0             0       1                   None


OP also requires None for df['reason'] if df['scored'] != 0 which might well be required with different data in the feat columns.
